# Erase part of mesh beyond intersection

Tags: modeling, mesh

I am trying to make a simple coffee (I'm a beginner but not using any tutorials, I like to explore things on my own), here's what I've got:
[image]

What I want to do now is erase the part of the torus mesh that is inside the cup, I tried joining the cylinder and torus but that didn't help much (Why would it help anyways). How can I delete that unwanted part? B-Selecting/Deleting vertices isn't very efficient and easy to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Know all the mesh [selection](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/selecting/index.html#selecting) tools.

In your case the [Lasso](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/selecting/introduction.html#lasso-select) or [Circle](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/selecting/introduction.html#circle-select) Select tool could help.

[image]

Other mentionworthy tools:

Expand Selection - <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Numpad+</kbd>
Reduce Selection - <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Numpad-</kbd>
Select Edge Loop - <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd>

You could also use a boolean modifier.

Select the torus and apply a boolean modifier with the cup as **Object** and the Method to **Difference**. Apply the modifier. Now you can use the [Select Linked](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/selecting/advanced.html#select-linked) Tool <kbd>L</kbd> to delete the unneeded vertices.

[image]

Comment: Perfect! I was too lazy to redo the cup so I simply C-selected the unwanted vertices, deleted them, and finally slightly moved the torus verts!